# SQL Server 2005: help to concatenate Nvarchar and Int

Tags: sql-server-2005, int, nvarchar

I have this block of code with an error because I'm using an `Int` variable inside a `Nvarchar`.

```
DECLARE @FattAnnoCorrente INT;
DECLARE @Tabscontianno1 NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Tabscontianno1 = 
N'<p align="left"><b>ANNO ' + @Anno1 + ' - </b><b>' + @FattAnnoCorrente + '<br>
  </b></p>
<table height="62" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2"
  width="501">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">FATTURATO<br>
      </td>
      <td valign="top">SCONTO<br>
      </td>
    </tr>' + CAST ((
                    SELECT  
                    td = SUM(TOTNETTORIGA),    '',
                    td = SCONTIESTESI
                    FROM .dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI 
                    INNER JOIN .dbo.RIGHEDOCUMENTI
                    ON PROGRESSIVO=IDTESTA AND TOTNETTORIGA <>'0'
                    WHERE  CODCLIFOR = @CodiceCliente AND .dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.DOCCHIUSO = '0' AND .dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.BLOCCATO = '0' AND .dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.TIPODOC = 'FVC'  AND .dbo.TESTEDOCUMENTI.ESERCIZIO = YEAR(GETDATE())
                    GROUP BY TESTEDOCUMENTI.ESERCIZIO,SCONTIESTESI
    FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE )
    AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'  </tbody>
</table>'+
    N'<BR/>' ;
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '**ANNO 2016 -** ' to data type int.

If I use

```
CAST(CAST(COALESCE(@FattAnnoCorrente) as int) as varchar(255))
```

I instead get these errors:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 154
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 173
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

Can you help me to solve this problem.

After insert it in the `nvarchar` variable I need to format it as money like that:

```
'€ ' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(@FattAnnoCorrente AS money), 105),',','.')
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to cast all `INT` types to `VARCHAR`..

in your case you are first casting them to INT..

change below statement

```
CAST(CAST(COALESCE(@FattAnnoCorrente) as int) as varchar(255))
```

to

```
cast(COALESCE(@FattAnnoCorrente,'somevalue') as varchar(255))
```

Comment: Some values like what?

Comment: @BigBlack:Some non null value for coalesce